# Jquery error with value having space dynamically

Tags: jquery

Find selection with dynamic value having space

like 'ltrY2axisTopUp Acmount'
I have

`var val = 'ltrY2axisTopUp Acmount'`
now i want to find like this

```
$(':input[value=' + val + ']')
```

It says

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #lsltrY2axis option[value=ltrY2axisTopUp Acmount]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(':input[value="' + val + '"]')
```

Notice `"` double quotes

Comment: Thanks, Very silly mistake :) i will marked it as best answer, as it will allow me after 10 minutes Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the `value` in `""`

```
$(':input[value="' + val + '"]')
```